# Commuting elements with coprime orders, $|xy| = |x||y|$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. If $x, y \in G$ commute and $\text{gcd}(|x|, |y|) = 1$, does it follow that $|xy| = |x||y|$?

EDIT: Progress so far. Let $C = |xy|$; then $x^C = (y^{-1})^C$. I am not sure what do from here though.

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: This is surely a duplicate...

Comment: @Qudit with the condition that $\gcd(|x|,|y|)=1$ along with the condition that $xy=yx$ it does.

Comment: Yes, I missed that part somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d$ be the order of $xy$. Now $(xy)^{mn}=e$. Hence $d|mn$.

Now $(xy)^d = e \implies x^d y^d = e \implies x^{dn} = e \implies m|nd$.

Since $m$ does not divide $n$, $m|d$.

Similarly $n|d$ since $gcd(m,n)=1$. Thus, $mn|d$.